# how to set width of img inside div tag?

Tags: css, image, ckeditor, inline

how to set width of img inside div tag?I want to keep this format and copy to ckeditor and auto resize all img inside div tag, so i can not use class.

```
    <div style='color:#222222;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;text-align: justify;img{width:500px!important};'>

    <img src="..."/> 
   <img src="..."/>
   <img src="..."/>
    </div>"
```

I tried but it is not working.

Comment: Depends How you want to showcase. If looking for full width, go ahead with width:100% . Provide the css codes alternately.

Comment: I want to copy this code to ckeditor so that i can not use javascript or <style></style>.Pls help !

Comment: `<div style='color:#222222;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;text-align: justify;'><img src="..." style="width:500px"></div>`

Comment: I want to auto resize all img inside the div code

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 500px;" >

<img src="..." style="max-width: 100%;"/>

</div>
```

Comment: can not use class because i want to keep this format in ckeditor

Comment: I want to auto resize all img inside, so can not use like this

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding class name for the div.Add the css for specific div image by using css

```css
.test img{
width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" style='color:#222222;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;text-align: justify;'>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: can not use class because i want to keep this format in ckeditor

Comment: In ck editor click source button to view code and add this class name.I have already tried to add class name and overwrite css in external css page.I works fine

Comment: you mean put the <style></style> in ckeditor ?
i already tried it, but the class is disappeared,

Comment: no..put the css in css file which u created for other files

Comment: i want to send document to another email and keeping the format. How i can send css file together?

Comment: are u creating the format email template using ckeditor or u need to send the code files to any one email ID

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the format and don't want to use classes you'll have to style each image individually.

```
<div style="blah width:500px">
<img src="..." style="max-width:100%" />
```

OR

```
<div style="blah">
<img src="..." style="width:500px;">
```

Comment: i want auto resize all image of the document inside div tag, because i have many images